# Android sherlock search view

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i added a up button in action bar sherlock by using below

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but how can i get the text after the back button as shown in this below link.(In the below link how is Books getting added after up button)

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set the title using `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("something" or R.string.someId)`, you can set the tag line or subtitle with `getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("something" or R.string.someId)`. You have to make sure to also call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true)` so it is actually displayed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the title text use `getSupportActionBar().getTitle();`
To set the title use `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);` OR `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(resId);`
To change the icon use `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(resId);`